# Permission denied when I try to get file contents from my home folder

Tags: php, linux, permissions

I run a cron job with a system user called `system_user` and I make the cron job save its output to the file `outputFile.txt` in my system_user's home folder  `/home/system_user/outputDir/outputFile.txt`.

This all works, but now I need to access this file within my php script which is located in `/var/www/html/scripts/phpScriptFile.php` and I'm getting a permission denied error.

I found out that the php scripts are run with `apache` user, so I did this:

```
sudo chown system_user:apache outputFile.txt
```

But this did not help.

If the cron outputs the file in let's say `/var/www/html/scripts/` folder then I do not get this permission error.

The reason I tried to move my outputFile.txt out of the /var/www/html folder is that if I leave it then it's possible to access it via http protocol and I don't want anyone seing the content of this file.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably some rights are not correct in the folder containing the file.

Also, maybe the group for apache user is not named `apache` or the group rights are not correctly assigned.

Reassign your user group:

```
sudo chown system_user:system_user outputFile.txt
```

And test giving general read permissions to the whole path:

```
chmod o+rx /home/system_user
chmod o+rx /home/system_user/outputDir
chmod o+r /home/system_user/outputDir/outputFile.txt
```

If this works (should do), then you can try to investigate if the group name was correct move the access rights to the group part.

Answer (score 1):

What are the permissions on outputFile.txt?

```
sudo chown system_user:apache outputFile.txt
```

That leaves system_user as the owner, but changes the group to apache. For that to work the file must be at least `rw-r-----` which could be accomplished by `chmod 640 outputFile.txt`.

Comment: the permissions are -rw-rw-r--